# Family tree in Biology and Category theory

Tags: category-theory, biology

I thought about family tree as a way to understand category theory more easily. The family tree is a diagram that provides detailed information about which family members were born to whom. Like the below picture.

[image]

**Our Goal :** Through this family tree, our goal is to find the most efficient methodological way to find our parents' generation.

Let's call category1 $C_1$ and category2 $C_2$ and category3 $C_3$ and category4 $C_4$. Isomorphism exists between $C_1$ and $C_2$. And isomorphism also exists between $C_3$ and $C_4$. Therefore we ca draw a diagram like this.
[image]

We need to conduct research such as genetic testing in a realistic way to find out the parent generation, but through isomorphism and res in category theory, we can infer how other generations can be discovered even if we only know one category.

I was thinking that I might be able to easily understand category theory this way, but I would like to know if this method is a good one. If this method is wrong, how can we easily understand category

Comment: Um... I was trying to understand what you're aiming for here, but I'm ultimately confused. I don't see any categories (as in, structures with objects and arrows, where the arrows admit certain operations subject to specific axioms) - can you please elucidate what exactly you would like to express?

Comment: @JohannesKloos I edited it. I hope this clears up your confusion.

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't understand what your family trees have to do with category theory. Can you please give a _formal_ definition of your categories, as in, what are the objects and arrows, what is the identity arrow for each object and how do you compose arrows? From your example, I just don't see how that is supposed to work.

Comment: @JohannesKloos I tried to approach this as mathematically as possible.  I hope this article helps you understand.

Comment: Well, maybe I'm wrong but maybe not: One problem is that what you are calling isomorphisms, morphisms for short, aren't truly morphisms because morphisms goes from objects to objects. Intuitively your categories are stated correctly as a collection of objects. You could define morphisms between two objects of the same category as the relation "they have a child". Therefore, in categories 1 and 2, there are morphisms between Bob and Sophia. The problem is that it is not directly to define "morphisms" from Bob and Sophia to David or Olivia. You require to define functors instead.

Comment: @BlueTomato I think you are right. I'll find out how to define the correct functor.

Comment: Paying attention to the arrows you will notice that from two objects you are deriving a third object; thats not the meaning of a morphism (in the context of your categories) unless you define a new category $D$ which objects are the given morphisms between two parents. Then you can define morphisms from category $D$ to categories 3 and 4. Yes, it becomes a morphism whose "domain" is a morphism (category theory is insane abstract). The functor let you capture more abstract relations. But this example is great, because it lets you conceptualice the definitions of category theory.

Comment: @BlueTomato I'm really thanks for your help! I've been thinking about your comment for quite some time and haven't come up with an answer yet.  How should I supplement the family tree to complete the abstract category theory by defining a new category $D$, as you commented?

Comment: @user1274233 you'd need to start with a category `C` and define a new category `D` on top of it, where the objects of `D` are precisely the arrows of `C`, and the arrows of `D` are _something_ that relates arrows, in such a way that it captures what you want `D` to model while respecting the axioms of categories. To be honest, I fear that since you're trying to understand the basics of category theory, this kind of construction will likely not do anything to help you - at least for me, it always takes a lot of time to untangle what's really going on when multiple categories are involved.

Comment: Another general comment - category theory is probably the wrong tool for modelling questions such as "what's the parent's generation of a group of people?". If anything, this seems like a question for, say, graph theory. While you can model graphs as categories, the framework of category theory doesn't really add anything worthwhile here (IMO).

Comment: @JohannesKloos Thanks for your comment. I understood your comment! I'll make an effort to understand category theory by another way.

Comment: Sir Kloos understood right my comment. But here we go again in a simplified manner (intuitively because morphisms needs to satisfy certain conditions). Suppose you category C is a collection of 3 persons: persons $X,Y,Z$. Let $f \in [X,Y]_C$ be the unique morphism of the category $C$ meaning that $X$ and $Y$ are related. Define the new category $D$ which unique element is the morphism $f$. Define the functor $F: f \to Z$. Notice that $f$ is morphism since is defined between objects in $C$ and $F$ is a functor since it relates categories $C$ and $D$. This are only intuitively ideas.

Comment: It is not so simple as the aforementioned example, because a category is a collection of objects and a set of morphisms between those objects. The morphisms need to satisfy some conditions. A functor is an assignment between two categories assigning objects to objects and morphisms to morphisms. For example, let $C$ category with objects $X,Y$ and $D$ category with objects $Z,W$. Let $f \in [X,Y]_C, g \in [Z,W]_D$. We define the functor $F$ such that $F:X\to Z$, $F:Y\to W$ and $F:f \to g$. In terms of two mother, father and son families, what does this represents?? Explain it.

Comment: Make sure you understand line by line I wrote. It cannot be develop more.